# Android - Como criar um loop corretamente em uma activity e pausa-lo e resumi-lo

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, jni

Tenho um projeto de um emulador de CHIP-8 que eu estou tentando portar para o android, o emulador todo é escrito em C++ logo criei uma biblioteca C++ no android studio e a adicionei ao meu projeto, o problema é, preciso manipular ele via activity, sempre que um usuário por exemplo pressionar o botão de voltar o loop de emulação deveria ser pausado, e sempre que um botão na tela fosse pressionado o loop deveria pausar, verificar qual "tecla" foi pressionada, realizar a devida ação no emulador e por fim resumir o loop, o problema é, o loop que criei fica sendo executado quando volta para a activity anterior ou crasha se eu por ele em segundo plano para acessar outro aplicativo, o modelo de loop que penso é semelhar ao `SDL_PollEvent` que permite manipular eventos de entrada mesmo com o loop em execução.

```
package com.samuelives.chipeight;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.samuelives.chipeight.emulator.RenderSurface;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Emulator extends AppCompatActivity {

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("CHIP-8");
    }

    private RenderSurface svEmulator = null;
    private boolean isRunning = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emulator);

        svEmulator = (RenderSurface)findViewById(R.id.svEmulator);

        initEmulator();

        if(!loadROM(getIntent().getStringExtra("gamePath"))){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Could not load game", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stopEmulator();
            finish();
        }

        cpuThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        svEmulator.onResume();
        isRunning = true;
        if(!cpuThread.isAlive()){
            cpuThread.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        svEmulator.onPause();
        isRunning = false;
        if(cpuThread.isAlive()) {
            try {
                cpuThread.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //stopEmulator();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isRunning = false;
        cpuThread.interrupt();
        stopEmulator();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        isRunning = false;
        cpuThread.interrupt();
        stopEmulator();
    }

    private Thread cpuThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(isRunning){
                execute();
                if(hasDraw()){
                    svEmulator.requestRender();
                }
            }

        }

    });

    public native void initEmulator();
    public native boolean loadROM(String path);
    public native void execute();
    public native void stopEmulator();
    public native boolean hasDraw();

}
```